# Can i prevent blur event from happening?

Tags: jquery, events

I have a simple example where i have an `input` field and i put a `blur` and `change` event on it:

**HTML**

```
<input name="test" value=""/>
```

**JS**

```
$('input').change(function(e){

 alert('change'); 

});

$('input').blur(function(e){

 alert('blur'); 
});
```

Is it possible to prevent the `blur` event from happening if the `change` event was triggered?

One way would be to define a boolean that changes when the change event was triggered, but I don't like it, is there a better way?

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JCExL) is an example you can play with.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Solved issue by [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GV3YY/5/)..**

```
 $('input').change(function(e){
  alert('change'); 
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   $(this).off("blur");
 });

$('input').focus(function(e){
   $(this).on("blur", function(e){
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
  alert('blur'); });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

use `.off`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/GV3YY/1/)**

```
$('input').change(function(e){
  alert('change'); 
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $(this).off("blur"); //$("input[name='test']").off("blur");
});

$('input').blur(function(e){  
  e.preventDefault();
 alert('blur'); 
});​
```

Comment: now `blur()` is not working. Its not working while lost focus of `input` element

Comment: First of all, it is better to use `$(this)` instead of `$("input[name='test']")`, secondly, like @MattLin mentioned, it removes the blur event entirely.

Comment: @MattLin, when will blur event fire?

Comment: The `blur` event is sent to an element when it loses focus. Originally, this event was only applicable to form elements, such as `<input>`. In recent browsers, the domain of the event has been extended to include all element types. An element can lose focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or by mouse clicks elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

`this.unbind('blur');` on the onchange call

Comment: but i don't want to lose my blur event, i only want to prevent it in case the change event was fired...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly the answer is to use `event.preventDefault();`
See http://jsbin.com/welcome/52201/edit for a demo.

Comment: that does not work, you just have `return;` that prevents the alert from happening...

Comment: OK thought you ment something else. In that case you could check http://jsbin.com/asubog/1/edit manually but .off() seems cleaner.