# Prevent blur() from running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap popover that becomes active on `focus` of an input. The popover contains a button in it to perform an ajax request.

I have a `blur` function that closes the popover if the user clicks away from the input:

```
$(document).on('blur','.open-popover',function(){        
    $(".popover").attr("style","");
    //and do other things too  
});
```

I am trying to prevent the `blur` function above from running if the user presses the button in the popover:

```
$(document).on('click','button',function(){
    //prevent the blur actions and 
    //do ajax stuff                                   
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: fire click() before blur() event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652852/jquery-fire-click-before-blur-event)

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509484/can-i-prevent-blur-event-from-happening is a better candidate.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [`stopImmediatePropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation)? If using jQuery, then event handlers are fired in the order that they are bound. Just bind the click before the blur, and run stopImmediatePropagation within the click event.

```
// bind click event first
$(document).on('click','button',function(event){
    // keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();                            
});

// then attach blur
$(document).on('blur','.open-popover',function(){        
    $(".popover").attr("style","");
    //and do other things too  
});
```